# What am I missing in making this simple jquery video player work?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 videos that I'm displaying on a page. `Onload`, both videos are hidden and simply a poster is shown. On clicking one of the buttons, a video is played. Which video is determined by some nested (hidden) data in the button.

I'm holding my videos in a variable like so:

```
var video_1 = '<video width="840" height="472" controls autoplay class="video_1">' +
   '<source src="/mov/video1.mp4"  type="video/mp4"  />' + 
   '<source src="/mov/video1.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>';

var video_2 = '<video width="840" height="472" controls autoplay class="video_2">' +
    '<source src="/mov/video2.mp4"  type="video/mp4"  />' +
    '<source src="/mov/video2.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>';
```

And my jquery to bring this up is like so:

```
$('#video_selection_wrap .play_wrap').live('click',function(){
    // get the nested data from the button
    var video = $(this).children('.data').text();

    // hide the poster
    $('.poster').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#main-movie').empty();
        switch(video) {
            case 'video_1':
                video_play = video_1;
            break;
            case 'video_2':
                video_play = video_2;
            break;
        }

        // load the appropriate video_play into the movie box
        $('#main-movie').html(video_play).show();
    });
});
```

The above code works a treat **for the first video I click**. What I was hoping would happen however was that if I clicked on another button, it would empty the movie container and load the other video - this isn't the case.

Can you see the problem?

I'm thinking it has something to do with the 'hide the poster' bit. Because its hidden the first time, the second time it doesn't `fadeOut`, and so it doesn't execute any of the code within its function. Is that how it works?

**Edit:**
Here is a working jsfiddle of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/RrC2u/

Comment: Your `var video_#` variables are declared without closing the variable and continuing to the next line, which you can't do in Javascript. (See http://jsfiddle.net/mZneB/, where in Firefox/Chrome Console, you'll see no errors.)

Comment: Ahh.. bugger - sorry - actually I only put those line spaces in here for readability and in my code its all on one line. I was wondering how to do what you have done though so that I could make the code more readable.

Comment: I've edited the post. My code is not producing any errors.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Note, you missed the `'` on the end of the first line, and on the second line for each... `;)`. Thanks for trying to format your code for readability, it really helps. `:)`

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle of the problem now http://jsfiddle.net/RrC2u/

Comment: You need to make the paths in the `VIDEO` `SOURCE` tags absolute, instead of relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `<div id="main-movie">` element is not properly closed:

```
<div id="movie-selection-wrap">
    <div id="main-movie">        <!-- not closed -->
    <div class="poster"></div>
</div>
```

Closing it fixes your issue:

```
<div id="movie-selection-wrap">
    <div id="main-movie"></div>
    <div class="poster"></div>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhamidi/RrC2u/1/).